# WPF connection path for SQL Server CE causes trouble

Tags: c#, wpf, database, sql-server-ce

I've got an issue with a small app I made, I've created a small app which uses a local database and connects to it with SQL Server CE.

Now, the path to the database file is :

```
public static string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=""Database1.sdf""";
```

When I run it on my computer (which was used to develop the app) it runs with no problems and used the databases info correctly.

When I copied the content of my `bin\Debug`" directory in to a rar, sent it to an other computer, extracted it all to a directory which contained the app files + the database file
(`Database1.sdf`), it just crashed whenever I pressed the "Log in" button I've made (which requires the database file).

In other words; it couldn't find the `database1.sdf` file for some reason.

By the way before I added the database, copying the `bin\Debug\` content and launching the app from a different computer worked well!

It probably has a simple solution which I did not figure out, please, if you know how to solve this issue, it'll be a great help to me.

Comment: It sounds to me that you are not sure if the problem is in the database path or something else. What the error message says?

Comment: It just crashes "The application has stopped working", and it is with the path, did some testing around and my computer has the same error when I give him a wrong path...

Comment: Please add error handling to your app! Is the SQL Server Compact runtime installed on the "other" computer?